# How do i loop throught this kind of javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hello i just want to know how to iterate this array

```

```
[
        {
            "0": {
                "player_id": "138",
                "player_name": "Pring",
                "profile_image": "",
                "score_card": [
                    "0"
                ],
                "total_score": 22
            },
            "1": {
                "player_id": "4",
                "player_name": "Poring 12",
                "profile_image": "",
                "score_card": [
                    "0",
                ],
                "total_score": 0
            },
            "date": "2017-09-21",
            "start_time": "17:40:00",
            "end_time": "18:00:00"
        }
]
```

```

or maybe group by players with lodash? im requesting to an api, but it seems that is not a cool one, or maybe im not good enough to perform this kind of arrays, (is my head hurt)

Comment: that is an array with one element - so, not much to `iterate` in reality

Comment: You loop through for objects properties using Object.keys or Object.getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: i can't write all the code, because SO doesn't leave me, but the real code has more than one objet in array, so it's needed to iterate @JaromandaX

Comment: oh, ok, so you want to iterate the array ... use .map or .forEach or .reduce - it's hard to tell which without you at least showing what output you require

Comment: this is all the code https://codepen.io/dcergo/pen/aLVOyv

Comment: What framework are you using to call this API?

Comment: Do you mean this simple looping on an array?
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: @Matthew idk what framework are using, because i'm not develop this api...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop through objects in an array, you can do this

```
for(var i=0; i<your_array.length; i++){
    var object = your_array[i]
    //your code here
}
```

If you want to loop through properties in an object, you can do this

```
for(var propName in object){
    var prop = object[propName]
    //Your code here
}
```

If you only want to loop through properties with numeric format name, you can do this

```
for(var propName in object){
    if(!isNaN(propName)){
        var prop = object[propName]
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Altogether,

```
for(var i=0; i<your_array.length; i++){
    var object = your_array[i];
    console.log("From " + object.start_time + " to " + object.end_time);

    for(var propName in object){
        if(!isNaN(propName)){
            var playerIndex = propName;
            var player = object[propName]

            console.log("Index = " + playerIndex + ", ID = " + player.player_id + ", Name = " + player.player_name);

        }

    }
}
```

Output

```
From 17:40:00 to 18:00:00
Index = 0, ID = 138, Name = Jay Patoliya
From 17:00:00 to 18:00:00
Index = 0, ID = 138, Name = Jay Patoliya
From 17:40:00 to 18:00:00
Index = 0, ID = 138, Name = Jay Patoliya
Index = 1, ID = 4, Name = Jay Patoliya
Index = 2, ID = 49, Name = John DiFulvio
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful!